# principle about SPAD for ToF ranging module from ST

Tags: optics, photons, photoelectric-effect

My colleagues are using VL53L0 from ST which is one ToF ranging module. I am trying to understand the principle about the SPAD(single-photon avalanche diode) and have read many materials on it.

From one paper, it reads ***the output of a SPAD is an electrical pulse for each detected photon***. Does it mean that the reflected photon won't arrive simultaneously? How much is the interval between arrival of two sequential photons? Can the digital circuitry detect the arrival interval?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: ToF: time of flight. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-flight_camera